# Using constant in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to define a constant in an initializer file and to use it into a model.

- config/initializers/constants.rb

  ```
  DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION = 15
  ```
- app/models/event.rb

  ```
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_validation :set_end_and_allday

    [...]

    def set_end_and_allday
      self.allDay ||= false
      self.end_event ||= self.start + DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION.minute
    end
  end
  ```

However, when it try to create a new event, it displays the following error in the logs:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Event::DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've made some searches on google, but I didn't find any solution (except defining constant into the model and not in the initializer... and that's not what i want to do).

Comment: Did you make sure to restart the server? Initializers only get run when the server first loads

Comment: Yes, by doing a simple `touch tmp/restart.txt` (I'm using pow).

Comment: It says it's looking for `Event::DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION`, try `::DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION` to access the constant at the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a scope problem: constant was in the root scope but it was searching the constant in the controller scope.

A simple '::DEFAULT_EVENT_DURATION' solved the issue.